# hiding report structure in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to design SSRS reports.

The report is successfully published and will have a link such as below:

```
http://hostname/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%Reports%2fDistributed&rs:Command=Render&rp_db_catalog=ts
```

Now when the user goes to the link,

```
http://hostname/ReportServer
```

it will show them the rest of the reports available which is a security concern.

Is there a way to hide the report structure from the user?

Thanks,
Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can "hide" it, nor should you. You'll need to use another method to secure your reports. Here are a few options:

- Secure within the web frontend you're currently using. You'll need to set up user accounts and roles, and permissions for folders. Here's the [MSDN starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), from there you can get to [securing folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155804%28v=sql.105%29).
- Deliver your reports through Sharepoint, see [this bit of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326358%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for a starting point.
- [Integrate ssrs in your application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) e.g. using the SOAP webservices, an asp.net or winforms app, or through [URL access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153563%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (that last option may even be quite close to what you want).